# Comparing and moving sets of files

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd

I need a batch file that looks in a file and moves a set of files
the problem is, is that it will need to compare files as there may be more than 1 set

the files correspond to each other

the first file in the set is `BIAK1234`
the second file is `BIPO1234`
Note the the 1234 is just the file number and will indicate what set it is a part of

So the batch file must find the set of files - `BIAK1234 and BIPO1234` and move them to another file

if `BIAK1234` does not exist then the script needs to end

But if there are files: BIAK1234, BIAK12345, BIPO 1234, BIPO12345 and BIPO123456

bipo123456 must remain until BIAK123456 exists and then it may be moved over

so how do I compare the files

I already know how to make a batch file move files and how to check to see if a file exists I am just not quite sure how to compare the files, determine the sets and move ONLY the sets

Comment: Please take the time to use proper punctuation and capitalization. As written, this question is extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled a bit with your question. At first I thought you were getting the file names from a text file. But your last paragraph led me to believe you are simply dealing with files in a folder.

As you say, the only moderately tricky bit is determining the individual set IDs. The solution is to use the SET command to either get a substring, or else replace the prefix with nothing. Type `set /?` from the command prompt to get more information.

In the solution below, I opted to use the search and replace method.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "source=c:\yourSourceFolder"
set "destination=c:\yourDestinationFolder"
set "file1=BIAK"
SET "file2=BIPO"

pushd "%source%"
for %%F in ("%file1%*") do (
  set "setID=%%F"
  set "setID=!setID:%file1%=!"
  if exist "%file2%!setID!" move "%%F","%file2%!setID!" "%destination%"
)
popd
```

Comment: Now would this move both file 1 and file 2 to a destination, and what if the destination is different for file 1 and file 2

Comment: @user233282 - Why not give it a try for your self? It will move both files to the destination. If you need different destinations, then you should have asked for it in the first place. Different destinations will require two MOVE statements.

Comment: When I try to run it I get this

Comment: @user233282 - Ummm, what do you get?

Comment: Do You have any ideas why it might be doing this

Comment: @JVarhol - I don't understand what you are showing or what the problem is with that pastebin post. You need to learn to take your time and carefully convey exactly what you have tried, and what the problem is. Had you been more clear, I (or someone else) would probably have answered the question days ago.

Comment: I am getting an error that I have invalid syntax I have tried several things to fix it with no luck Please help

Thanks,
Jvarhol